# How can i build a custom angular component with the width settable in CSS?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-material2

This [site](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overviewhttp://) states, that I can change the width of the side-nav with CSS like this:

```
md-sidenav {
   width: 200px;
}
```

This arouses the following question for me: Can I apply the standard CSS properties like `width`, `position`, etc... to custom components without to define them in my component?

Example:

```
my-component {
    width: 500px;
}
```

I tried it out and it does not work. So I think, that the answer is no, am I right?

To find out how they set `width` with CSS I have read through the sources on [github](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/sidenav/drawer.ts). But I can't figure out how they did that. The component has no `width` property. So, how did they make `width` accessible with CSS?

---

**EDIT:**

To clarify the question I will give you the following example:

I have programmed the following component:

**test.component.html:**

```
<p>test works!</p>
```

**test.component.css:**

```
p {
   border: 2px solid red;
}
```

**test.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

This is my app root, that gets bootstrapped by angular:

**app.component.html:**

```
<app-test>

</app-test>
```

**app.component.css**

```
app-test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Test App';
  constructor() { }

}
```

The `_app.component.css_` shows what I want to do. I want to set the size of the `_app-test_` component with CSS. I saw this working with the `_side-nav_` component of the angular material and I want to understand how they have enabled the `_side-nav_` to get its width from the parent components CSS file.

Comment: [This guide](https://github.com/willshowell/material2/blob/cc8a3b9601cb8fcaad0060a470935e7e7d13f0b3/guides/customizing-component-styles.md) will hopefully be merged in soon and covers customizing component css.

Comment: Is no one there who can help me?

Comment: Try to use `:host { height: ..., width: ... }` in `app.component.css`. I think that will accomplish what you're asking.

Comment: I dont want to accomplish it that way. I want to understand why the Syntax i wrote in my question is working with _md-sidenav_. I have studied the sources, but i can't figure out why the width css rule can be applied to_md-sidenav_.

Comment: The sidenav component has view encapsulation turned off. If you do the same in your app component, it should have the same effect.

Comment: I already tried to set the encapsulation of_app-test_ to none. The width still does not affect_app-test_

Comment: Ah ok I was misreading something. Add `:host { display: block; }` to `app-test`'s styles. Components default to displaying as inline elements which cannot take height/width properties.

Comment: @ Will Howell: Thats it, thank you. I will write it down as an answer for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Question was answered with the comment of Will howel beneath my question. This post should recap what I have learnered through the comments of the other users, so that people with a similar question could learn from it.

The template of every component is wrapped in a host element. In the sidenav example, this element is the *md-sidenav* tag. The host element is a regular dom-element, wherefore you can add standard css rules to that element. That means that you can apply css rules like *width* to every custom angular component out of the box. But you have to take into account that you need to set the *display* property of the host element to *block*. If you don't do that, the width rule has no effect to the element.
To accomplish that in case of the *md-sidenav* component they applied the class *mat-drawer* within the *component-decorator* to the element.

exerpt from *sidenav.ts:*

```
    host: {
    'class': 'mat-drawer mat-sidenav',
    ...
  },
```

Then they set the rule in the stylesheet.
Exerpt of *drawer.scss:*

```
 .mat-drawer {
     @include mat-drawer-stacking-context();

     display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE After OP's edit:**

Change your `app.component.css` to this:

```
:host {
  display:block; 
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

This will apply the styles on the `<app-test>` selector. Here is the [**plunker demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/lJ2ktyeMkSfcDQq6rKQe?p=preview).

---

**ORIGINAL Answer:**

You can override the default styles of Material 2 components by setting `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the component.

Then you'll have to define the styles in your component.css file.

```
.mat-sidenav {
    width: 250px;
}
```

See this [plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/qgYOM0k9E3ESsNkHgZrZ?p=preview) with user defined width.

---

**Update after OP's comments:**

Suppose you have a component file, `my.component.ts` and it has styles in `my.component.css`, you can define the styles of the component in the css file and apply then on the component selector using `:host`.

> my.component.ts :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-comp', 
    templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent{
}
```

> my.component.css :

```
:host {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

> my.component.html:

```
<h2>Some Heading in the Template </h2>
```

Comment: I believe the correct Component metadata property name  is `encapsulation`, not `ViewEncapsulation`. See [here](https://angular.io/api/core/Component)

Comment: Correct, my bad. Updated plunker and answer

Comment: In your demo, neither the alternate selector nor the change to selection are required. See [forked plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/VhqUrTfZX8gCc4bt63FQ?p=preview)

Comment: @Will Hoowell, your gorked demo will work in this specific case, however it wont run for all components.  Try setting height of `md-toolbar` your way

Comment: Sorry guys, but that did not answer my Question. What do I have to do to create a component which width can be set with css?

Comment: Every component's width can be set using css. What is your exact requirement?

Comment: As an example a div has the property width. Thus i can set its width in my css file. Now I build a custom component _mycomponent_. Does it have the width property out of the box, hence i can set it with css?

Comment: No it does not. You have to define a css class and set the properties in thay class. I'll update my answer with the solution you want, if I understood correctly.

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify what I want to know. I would be pleased if you can help me.

Comment: @Faisal But i want to know, why this Syntax '.mat-sidenav {
    width: 250px;
}' is working. That did they implement in their component, that i can set the width like that. They dont use the host selector: 
https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview

Comment: `.mat-sidenav` is the css class provided by Material2, we can use that to override the default styles with out own.

Comment: they dont use .mat-sidenav. Just the element selector _mat-sidenav_

Comment: yes because they are using `:host` - you got the answer what you wanted to achieve, what is the problem now?

Comment: no i didn get the answer I wanted to achieve. I want to know, why this part of code is possible: md-sidenav {
  width: 200px;
}

Comment: Watch this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/7vjuEKNBqIq2b4ITPZ2s?p=preview Why can they set padding of _.example-sidenav_ in CSS. That does not work out of the box. The component _side-nav_ does not have the property padding. Why can it be set with CSS?